# Is EF Lazy Loading a real Proxy Pattern?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, lazy-loading, proxy-pattern

I know EF use **Proxy Pattern** to implement **lazy loading**.

1.Stand Proxy Pattern:

[image]

In the proxy pattern,[Proxy] will **not** be **inherited** from [RealSubject].

2.EF

In lazy loading,[Proxy] class **will** be **inherited** from [RealSubject].

So this is **not** **exact** the same as stand Proxy Pattern.

But why they called it Proxy Pattern?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about patterns and not solving an actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is in the name: it is a **pattern**, not a rigid rule. It is a concept, which it is described by a known name, so people who know the pattern will understand it although the implementation differs in the details.

This is valid for patterns in any domain.